# Unreal Engine C++ SpawnActor Cast

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm coding a multiplayer game in Unreal Engine 4.15.0 and it's almost working except for a freaking line of code that I can't figure out it's behavior. The problem is that I have a OnlinePawn Blueprint that inherits from a C++ base class AOnlinePawn. Whenever a player joins the match I spawn this Blueprint and cast it to an array that I update constantly receiving data.

The problem is that the following code that tries to casts AActor* returned by the function to AOnlinePawn* fails and returns null, it's a cast issue as it is indeed spawned.

The cast:

```
playersInstances[i] = Cast<AOnlinePawn>(GetWorld()->SpawnActor(OnlinePlayer->GeneratedClass, &position, &rotator));
```

The blueprint reference:

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UBlueprint> OnlinePlayerBP(TEXT("Blueprint'/Game/Blueprints/OnlinePawn.OnlinePawn'"));
OnlinePlayer = OnlinePlayerBP.Object;
```

The Blueprint description, stating the parent class:

[image: The Blueprint description, stating the parent class.]

So, what's the problem here? There's anyway I can improve my workflow? There's a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your cast line is not correct. SpawnActor is a template function, you are not supposed to cast it manually like that. Instead, you should simply give it the type you want to use. Try it like this:

```
AOnlinePawn* NewActor = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AOnlinePawn>(GetClass(),  &position, &rotator);
```

EDIT:

You're welcome. So if you actually want To reference a blueprint in your code you can either use the constructor helpers or the class finder.

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UBlueprint> onlineSpawnBP(TEXT("Blueprint'/Game/FirstPersonCPP/Blueprints/OnlineSpawn'")); //replace with the right path to your blueprint in your project
     if (onlineSpawnBP)
     {
         AOnlinePawn* NewActor = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AOnlinePawn>(GetClass(),  &position, &rotator); 
     }
```

Comment: According to the docs there are [non-templated versions of the function](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UWorld/SpawnActor/6/index.html) but even the example there uses the templated version, so it looks like that is the recommended way

Comment: There's just one more thing, this line isn't in the AOnlinePawn class space, so GetClass() won't work (even if it was, I want to spawn the blueprint that inherits AOnlinePawn not the AOnlinePawn itself). How could I get a reference to the OnlinePawn blueprint class that matches this function signature? By the way thank you @Moums!

Comment: Corrected the post for further readers, thanks for the help guys!